# Intl.Numberformat, currencyDisplay: "narrowSymbol" not supported on Next.Js 9.4.4

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js

I'm using Next.JS 9.4.4

When trying to use:

```
new Intl.NumberFormat('en-GB', { style: 'currency', currency: currency, useGrouping: true, currencyDisplay: 'narrowSymbol'});
```

I receive the error:

```
RangeError: Value narrowSymbol out of range for Intl.NumberFormat options property currencyDisplay
    at new NumberFormat
```

narrowSymbol is a supported property as you can see [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/NumberFormat/NumberFormat) and I have used it successfully on another project that wasn't using Next.

Am I missing something, or is there perhaps a workaround?

Comment: As you are using Nextjs, is Your Javascript running on the client or server.

Comment: In this case, both

Comment: Same issue here, it only seems to happen on Firefox

Comment: Safari iOS only added support for `narrowSymbol` in 14.5 and Safari Mac OS in 14.1. Your options are to polyfill or use `symbol` instead

Answer (score 3):

The problem might be that the browser you're using doesn't support the `narrowSymbol` currency display. You can check with Can I Use here:

https://caniuse.com/?search=currencyDisplay

You'll see how a few browsers like Safari have a note:

`Doesn't support currencyDisplay: 'narrowSymbol'.`

For these browsers that don't support it, you may need to polyfill `Intl.NumberFormat` so that you have access to `narrowSymbol`.

There are lots of polyfill options out there. I've used formatjs.io for this exact issue. You can find out more here:

https://formatjs.io/docs/polyfills/intl-numberformat

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem on iOS14 with React Native. narrowSymbol was simply not supported.

Comment: @BillSomen I ended up by not using narrowSymbol

Comment: Good move, that's what I finally did

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the server side code is causing the problem, there shouldn't be a problem with client side code.

A possible solution is is to install node with full Internationalisation support (ICU).

Here is the link to the [node doc](https://nodejs.org/api/intl.html)

Answer (score -2):

This does not work for you?

```js
function formatMoney(amount) {
  return new Intl.NumberFormat('en-GB', {
    style: 'currency',
    currency: 'GBP',
    useGrouping: true,
    currencyDisplay: 'narrowSymbol',
  }).format(amount)
}

console.log(formatMoney(1000.00))
```

Comment: No, that is nearly identical to what I have. The problem I'm experiencing is around the narrowSymbol property on currencyDisplay